# PHP date showing weird year/date from timestamp

Tags: php, date, timestamp

I have the following timestamp:

```
1341111034380
```

Which equates to:

```
Sun, 01 Jul 2012 02:50:34 GMT
```

However, when I try to format this using:

```
date("F j, Y, g:i a", 1341111034380)
```

I get:

```
February 12, 44468, 5:53 am
```

Any ideas why it would do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the wrong units.

1341111034380 is in milliseconds, whereas a proper timestamp is in seconds, which is what PHP expects.

If you want to use it in PHP, you should convert it to seconds.

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", floor(1341111034380/1000));
```

Comment: no, it is a timestamp, only the last 3 digits are miliseconds!

Comment: Correct, simply divide by 1000. $timestamp = floor($timestamp/1000);

Comment: Ahhhhh... good catch! Thank you, will select you in 9 minutes when it lets me :p

Comment: @MihaiIorga It is a time, but a standard timestamp is measured in seconds and that is what most things expect.

Comment: @loganfsmyth your answer is still incorect! the time is timestamp + milliseconds.

Comment: @MihaiIorga It's a number. The entire thing is milliseconds. By dividing by 1000 you convert the units to seconds. The last 3 digits are the portion that is < 1s, and therefore discarded, but the whole number is still milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
echo date("F j, Y, g:i a", substr(1341111034380, 0, 10));
```